# Issue with beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a `beforeunload` function:

```
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
if(inFormOrLink){
    return inFormOrLink ? "Do you really want to close?" : null;
}});
```

This function works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox. For Firefox I use this function:

```
if(inFormOrLink){
    var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
    var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload';
    myEvent(chkevent, function(e) {    
        var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure to leave the page?';  // a space
        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
        return confirmationMessage;
    });
}
```

This works fine. My issue is like above function works when I get the value of inFormLink false.

Comment: I don't understand what "My issue is like above function works when I get the value of inFormLink false" means. What happens when the value is false? If your problem in Firefox or Chrome or both?

Comment: In above function when i don't want to call popup i use inFormOrLink= false but in below case i did the same but popup appears

Comment: if `inFormOrLink` is `true` then what you're saying can't be happening. Is it possible that this snippet of code is run multiple times? Because if it's even run once with `inFormOrLink` turned on then the event will stay bound until you try to leave the page...

Comment: Got it but if it has calling many then why my above  code works fine in chrome but for mozila i use below code in same scenario but its not working